# I want to use git svn to track two remote branches in a Subversion repository. How?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

I've been trying all day to configure by hand a git repository locally based on a very large remote subversion repository. It has the default configuration (trunk, branches, tags) but I only want a small portion of the data.

I don't fully understand Git's :refs/remotes/* syntax in .git/config, even though many posts online have explanations for editing it and fetching.

I have my svn repo stored to an `$SVNR` environment variable. It's roughly equal to  `https://svn.ourserver.com/svn/`

**I want a git `master` branch to track $SVNR/branches/production and a `development` branch to track the remote svn trunk.**

I have a huge repo and only want a few revisions, and to construct my git repo to be much smaller subset of the remote SVN repo, like so. Following lots of other sites and posts about doing this, I ended up with this so far as my clone command:

`git svn clone -r2000:HEAD --prefix=svnrepo/ --authors-file=/Users/phpguru/Sites/authors.txt $SVNR/branches/production gitrepo`

Now I can `cd gitrepo` and see my `.git/config`

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = https://svn.ourserver.com/svn/projectfoo/branches/production
    fetch = :refs/remotes/svnrepo/git-svn
[svn]
    authorsfile = /Users/phpguru/Sites/authors.txt
```

Now lets take that apart for a moment. Why isn't `master` listed here? Where did `git-svn` come from? That doesn't exist in my SVN repo. I don't understand why the fetch ref doesn't say `fetch = master:refs/remotes/svnrepo/branches/production` ? Can I change "svn" to "projectfoo" as so many examples show?

When I do a `git svn info` and `git branch -a` I do see a master branch. It appears that master is properly tracking branches/production as I wanted.

My question is, how do I now create a `development` branch that is tracking the remote trunk?

I've tried a dozen different ways, including editing .git/config with some logical fetch lines:

```
fetch = branches/*:refs/remotes/svnrepo/branches/*
fetch = development/*:refs/remotes/svnrepo/trunk/*
```

but nothing worked.

```
$ git branch --track development remotes/svnrepo/trunk
error: the requested upstream branch 'remotes/svnrepo/trunk' does not exist
hint: 
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint: 
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.
```

Or,

```
$ git branch development --track remotes/git-svn-trunk
fatal: Cannot setup tracking information; starting point 'remotes/git-svn-trunk' is not a branch.
```

Comment: `git svn`, as the result of a bug fix, no longer allows remote Subversion branches to be treated as an upstream branch for a local Git branch for tracking purposes.

Comment: This is a disappointment. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Curious - what did yo do instead? One git repo for each branch and merging in svn?

Comment: As @chepner said, `git svn` is no longer an option. I copied the SVN contents at the last commit point, recursively `rm -rf`'d .svn dirs and committed my work to a fresh git repo, dumping svn altogether.